# Join head table with position table with laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have the following construction:

(Laravel Version 5.4)

I have a head table (series), and a table with associated positions (posts). The positionstable has three values whose determine, whether the posts should be displayed, or even not. The series table has this information as well.
These columns are: 'published' (boolean), 'published_from' (datetime) and 'published_to' (datetime).

To display the posts, the series and the posts, had to be published (published = 1), and the actual date/time has to be grater, or euqal, than the published_from value, of the series and the post, and the actual date/time has to be lower or equal than the published_to value, as well.

To chek whether the postion should be displayed, I wrote a eloquent scope:

```
public function scopePublishedRestriction($query)
        {
            $date = Carbon::today();
            $today = date('Y-m-d', $date->getTimestamp());

            $query->accessible()
                ->join('learning_series', function ($join) use ($today) {
                    $join->on($this->table . '.learning_serie_id', 'learning_series.id')
                        ->where('learning_series.published', 1)
                        ->whereDate('learning_series.published_from', '<=', $today)
                        ->where(function ($join) use ($today) {
                            $join->orWhere(function ($join) use ($today) {
                                $join->whereDate('learning_series.published_to', '>=', $today);
                            })
                                ->orWhere('learning_series.published_to', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                        });
                })
                ->where($this->table . '.published', 1)
                ->where($this->table . '.published_from', '<=', $today)
                ->where(function ($query) use ($today) {
                    $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($today) {
                        $query->whereDate($this->table . '.published_to', '>=', $today);
                    })
                        ->orWhere($this->table . '.published_to', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                });

            return $query;
        }
```

The created SQL-statement is correct,

```
select * from `brshop_docs_learning_posts` 
inner join `brshop_docs_learning_series` on `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`learning_serie_id` = `brshop_docs_learning_series`.`id` 
and `brshop_docs_learning_series`.`published` = ? 
and date(`brshop_docs_learning_series`.`published_from`) <= ? 
and ((date(`brshop_docs_learning_series`.`published_to`) >= ?) or `brshop_docs_learning_series`.`published_to` = ?) 
    where `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`visible` = ? 
    and `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`active` = ? 
    and `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`published` = ? 
    and `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`published_from` <= ? 
    and ((date(`brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`published_to`) >= ?) or `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`published_to` = ?) 
    and `brshop_docs_learning_posts`.`deleted_at` is null
```

I think, the merge of the collections is wrong. For example, every post in this collection has the ID of the series. So every column, that exists in the series table and in the posts table has the value of the series table.

Thank you for your help ;-)

Markus

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with whereHas()

```
    public function scopePublishedRestriction($query)
    {
        $date = Carbon::today();
        $today = date('Y-m-d', $date->getTimestamp());

        $query->accessible()
            ->whereHas('serie', function($query) use($today){
                $query->where('learning_series.published', 1)
                    ->whereDate('learning_series.published_from', '<=', $today)
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($today) {
                        $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($today) {
                            $query->whereDate('learning_series.published_to', '>=', $today);
                        })
                            ->orWhere('learning_series.published_to', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                    });
            })
            ->where($this->table . '.published', 1)
            ->where($this->table . '.published_from', '<=', $today)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($today) {
                $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($today) {
                    $query->whereDate($this->table . '.published_to', '>=', $today);
                })
                    ->orWhere($this->table . '.published_to', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            });

        return $query;
    }
```